# LogStash Ruby for dividing fields and stored into new field

Tags: logstash

Below is my event.

```
{  
   "system":{  
      "cpu":{  
         "cores":2,
         "system":{  
            "pct":1.1988
         },
         "user":{  
            "pct":0.5487
         }
      }
   },
   "type":"metricsets"
}
```

the value of `system.cpu.user.pct` should be divided by `system.cpu.cores` and new value should be stored in  `system.cpu.user.pct`.

I tried as mentioned below but it did not work:

```
ruby {
      code => "event.set('system.cpu.user.pct', system.cpu.user.pct / system.cpu.cores)"
}

ruby {
       code => "event['system.cpu.user.pct'] = event['system.cpu.user.pct'] / event['system.cpu.cores']"
}

ruby {
        code => "event['[system][cpu][user][pct]'] = event['[system][cpu][user][pct]'] / event['[system][cpu][cores]']"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
ruby {
    code => "event.set('[system][cpu][user][pct]', 
    event.get('[system][cpu][user][pct]') / event.get('[system][cpu][cores]'))"
}
```

You can read more on how it works [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html).